# How do I validate for price input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input and I want to validate this input. Input should only accept numbers and one dot. Such as 2.222 3745.299. I used regex for this and when I tried it in codepen I didn't see a problem. But when I try it in my react application, I cannot enter dot as a value. It does not accept strings and special characters as I want, but also not in the dot. I do the validation like this:

```js
const { name, value } = e.target;

if ((name === 'Price' || name === 'TotalPrice') && /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/.test(value) && value !== '.') {
  values[name] = +value;
  setProduct(values);
}
```

Input:

```js
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  id="priceInput"
  name="Price"
  ref={priceInput}
  value={product.Price}
  onChange={(e) => handleChangeInput(e)}
  onKeyUp={(e) => calcTotalPrice(e)}
  onInput={() => setIsPriceActive(true)}
/>
```

Comment: You can simplify `{(e) => handleChangeInput(e)}` into `{handleChangeInput}`. Same for `onKeyUp`.

Comment: I'd modify the RegExp to `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/`; that is to say at least one digit, optionally followed by a dot and at least one digit. Your current version would accept as valid also `.9534` or `123.`

Comment: Why should name equal one of two values?

Comment: I tried it, but when I try to delete all the values in the input, there is one last digit and I cannot delete it. At the same time, it still does not accept dot. @secan

Comment: @Dogukan If you want to allow an empty string, the RegExp becomes `/^$|^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/`

Comment: as secan mentioned /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/ should be your regex for the use case, if the problem still persists then ping again

Comment: I forgot the mention, this is in my handleChangeInput function. I have another inputs and  if statements like this. @GetSet

Comment: Also, I'd change from `<input type="text" ... />` to `<input type="number" ... />`; if the browser supports it, it will already apply some sort of filtering for the allowed characters, if it the browser does not support it, it will fallback to `type="text"` and you have your RegExp kicking in.

Comment: Does type "number" take a period symbol @secan?

Comment: Oh, I understand. But input still doesn't accept dot. Why is that? @secan

Comment: Is it possible your system and/or browser are set to use a comma instead of a dot as separator for decimals?

Comment: yes input type number takes decimal numbers too

Comment: If possible share the code snippet on codepen

Comment: I tried it in a different browser, it's still the same. As you said, I used type = "number" but this time when I try to delete all of it, it stays 0 in the input and adds the remaining numbers, like 056.77 02666.98. @secan